# Wordpress wp-insert-post image attachment within content

Tags: php, wordpress

I’m creating a custom post submit form for wordpress and at the moment I can create the post and have the image uploaded and attached to the post but the next step im struggling at - I’m looking to have the uploaded image automatically displayed on the post, ive looked into the featured image option but just can’t get it to work

```
$my_post = array();
$my_post['post_title'] = $newid;
$my_post['post_content'] = $imageurl1.$imageurl.$config_basedir.$uploaddir.$id . ".gif". $imageurl2;
$my_post['post_author'] = 1;
$my_post['post_status'] = draft;
$my_post['post_category'] = array($a);
// Insert the post into the database
$post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);
//
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($id . ".gif"), null );
$attachment = array();
$attachment['post_mime_type'] = $wp_filetype['type'];
$attachment['post_title'] = $newid;
$attachment['post_content'] = '';
$attachment['post_status'] = 'inherit';
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $id . ".gif", $post_id)
require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $filename);
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attach_id,  $attach_data);
set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attach_id);
//
wp_redirect( site_url()."?p=$post_id" ); exit();
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Updated the code to include the wp_insert_post section

Answer (score 0):

Use set_post_thumbnail. You can pass in the post object or ID. Thumbnail ID is the media attachment ID.

```
set_post_thumbnail( $post, $thumbnail_id );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - ive added this before as set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attach_id); but that didnt work tho i may be doing something stupid

Comment: When you did that was $post_id set as well as $attach_id?

Comment: Include the code you have on the wp_insert_post hook and I'll point you in the right direction.